# R not recognising equalities correctly

Tags: r

I am trying to classify matrices based on which row has the highest value. My code works correctly, except for when the first and third row have the same value - then the output is that the third value is larger than the first. 
 For example, when I use the following matrix:

```
        , , 1

           [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
    [1,] 0.5+0i 0.5+0i 0.5+0i
    [2,] 0.0+0i 0.0+0i 0.0+0i
    [3,] 0.5+0i 0.5+0i 0.5+0i
```

And the following bit of the code:

```
  null   <- 0
  neg   <- 0
  pos   <- 0
  equal <- 0

  for(i in 1){
   if(Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[2,1,i]) &&
      Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])){
         neg<-neg+1
    }
    if(Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[1,1,i]) &&
       Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])){
          pos<-pos+1
    }


  if(Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[1,1,i]) &&
  Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])){
      null<-null+1
  }
  if((Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[2,1,i]) && 
    Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[3,1,i]))||
    (Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])&&
    Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])||
  (Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,1])&&
  Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[1,1,i]))|| 
  Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[2,1,i]) &&
  Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,i]))){
     equal<-equal+1

 }
}
    null
    neg
    pos
    equal
```

I get the following output, which is clearly wrong:

```
> null
[1] 0
> neg
[1] 0
> pos
[1] 1
> equal
[1] 0
```

However, the code works correctly if all the three values are the same (I tried it for all values being 0), giving me a 1 for Equal and a 0 for Pos.

Any ideas why this error might occur? Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can match these values based on position as well? So if value from first column is max, you would deem it negative, positive for the value from third column and so on? Zdravo. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you mean. Basically, these matrices represent stationary states of Markov chains, so the value from the first row is the probability of a population having a negative growth rate, the third of positive growth rate and the middle row of 0. Živjo :)

Comment: What is `format(pie.ch[1,1,1], digits = 16)`? How about `format(pie.ch[3,1,1], digits = 16)`?

Comment: Please use line breaks, spaces  and clearer formatting on your code to make it readable.

Comment: I made the formatting somewhat less brutal but it still needs work to improve readability. I'm also not sure you need all that code to provide a minimal example.

Comment: Then you must give us a way to create your array. Can you please edit the question with the output of `dput(pie.ch)` or if it is too big with a subset that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem was in fact floating points and I managed to solve it. In terms of editing the question with `dput(pie.ch)` the output is not comprehensible, as an array of many matrices is transformed in a large chunk of numbers, therefore I would prefer not to edit the question with it

Answer (score 1):

Without a dput of your object, it's hard to say what your problem might be, but here's what I typically look for when a logical test for equality isn't meeting my expectations.

```
(x <- 0.5+0i + 1e-8)
# [1] 0.5+0i
Re(x) == 0.5
# [1] FALSE
```

The real portion of `x` is not, in fact, equal to `0.5`. It just displays as if it's `0.5`. You can examine this with `as.character(x)`, which here will show `"0.50000001+0i"`.  To really drill down, try `format(x, digits = 16)`.

```
(x <- 0.5+0i + .Machine$double.eps)
format(x, digits = 16)
# [1] "0.5000000000000002+0i"
```

As it is, though, your problem is not reproducible. Generating the array with the data you represented and running your code, `pos` is `0` and `equal` is `1` after executing.

```
pos <- 0
equal <- 0
pie.ch <- array(0, dim = c(3, 3, 3))
pie.ch[,,1] <- matrix(rep(c(0.5+0i, 0+0i, 0.5+0i), 3), 3)
pie.ch

# , , 1

#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
# [1,] 0.5+0i 0.5+0i 0.5+0i
# [2,] 0.0+0i 0.0+0i 0.0+0i
# [3,] 0.5+0i 0.5+0i 0.5+0i

...
i <- 1
if(Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])&&Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])){pos<-pos+1}
if((Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])&&Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[3,1,i]))||(Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])&&Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])||(Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,1])&&Re(pie.ch[3,1,i])>Re(pie.ch[1,1,i]))||Re(pie.ch[1,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])&&Re(pie.ch[2,1,i])==Re(pie.ch[3,1,i]))){equal<-equal+1}
pos
# [1] 0
equal
# [1] 1
```